# Setting up the emission via script for a particle system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particles

I have a problem with particle emission. 
I have a gun that shoots smoke when a button is pressed. I have set up the particle system in a way that it looks ok when its emitting (in the particle system settings) (first picture).

[image: smoke example]

The problem now lies that when I try to emit the particle only by the code it completely changes how the emission looks.

According to the particle effect I have 1500 particles with smoke.emit(30); which is way more than the 1000 set up by the emitter option.

But it appears it just clumps the particles together and just increases the number of particles on the same position as others.

Is there any way I can achieve a similar graphical setting as the emitter shows?

Thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the [`ParticleSystem.emission`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-emission.html) module of the `ParticleSystem` and set the [`EmissionModule.rateOverTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.EmissionModule-rateOverTime.html) and [`EmissionModule.rateOverDistance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.EmissionModule-rateOverDistance.html)

```
particleSystem.emission.rateOverTime = 1000;
particleSystem.emission.rateOverDistance = 25;
```

Comment: @LosKartoflos no .. look at the linked API .. they use exactly that in the exmaples. The `emission` of course is read-only but not its properties

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use ParticleSystem.Play(); and ParticleSystem.Stop();

Seems like it acts differently if you use the above function instead of ParticleSystem.emit(1);